# Proper way to build clang and libc++ together (bootstrap)

Tags: cmake, clang, clang++, libc++

I would like to build a recent clang + llvm + libc++. I'm currently on a system (based on CentOS 6.6) where I can't easily get binary packages of clang, but where I can set up a GCC recent enough for building clang (for example 4.9), by setting some environment variables.

I'd like my version of clang to be

- Portable, that is no hardcoded paths (e.g. using `-rpath $ORIGIN`)
- Neither dependent on the system gcc nor the imported gcc 4.9 (that is, their C/C++ runtimes)
- In particular, neither the compilers, the compiler-as-a-library libclang.so, nor programs built with the new compiler should depend on libstdc++, but they should use the newly built libc++.

I can do this, but it involves putting clang, llvm, libc++, libc++abi (and things I might have forgotten) in one tree, building clang from one build directory, then setting a lot of flags blindly and building it again from a second build directory.

Is there another proper way of bootstrapping clang with libc++? I believe there must be, since the official binaries of llvm & clang are self-sufficient as I described above.

Comment: The "official" packages probably do it either using your method (putting it all in a single source tree) or by staggered building (build Clang without libc++, build libc++ with new clang, build new clang with libc++).

Comment: By the way, why don't you download a source package for one of the bigger distributions and see how they do it?

Answer (score 7):

I've been curious about this myself and don't think there is a proper, "blessed" way of bootstraping clang with li
bc++.

In my experience, clang installed from repositories depends on libstdc++, and so does clang installed from binary
distributions available at http://www.llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.7.0 (I've tried the one for Ubuntu 14.04).  A few differences between repo clang and that from llvm.org:

- I haven't seen a repo clang with libc++; I had to build it
  separately.  Clang from llvm.org does come with libc+
  +.
- The llvm.org clang appears to have the library location, relative to
  where it lives, hardcoded; same goes for some headers (!) that   live in the lib directory.

Considering that clang from repositories and llvm.org depends on libstdc++, I would say that there is no proper wa
y of getting rid of that dependency, at least not on Linux systems I've played with, which include Ubuntu, Amazon Linux, CentOS, and Fedora.

Having said this, however, I find that even using clang dependent on libstdc++ allows one to produce programs that depend on libc++ instead of libstdc++.  Even though it is possible to build a clang+llvm setup that does not itself depend on libstdc++, as you have found already, I don't think it's necessary to jump through all those hoops.

In case you find it helpful, I have a brief article on this at [http://www.omniprog.info/clang_no_gcc.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20181014103429/http://www.omniprog.info/clang_no_gcc.html) (also see [this](http://tolik1967.azurewebsites.net/clang_bootstrap.html))

I'm still experimenting with all this and will update this answer if I come across something interesting.